# Comparing dates and show the remainder left til expiry date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@if (DateTime.Today < item2.VoucherCampaign.ExpiryDate)
{
    <h3>Expires: <span style="color:#FF0000"> Days Remaining</span></h3>
}
```

This is my mark up right now. I am trying to compare the date of today to the expiry date and than output the days remaining. I have no idea on going about putting the count of days left in my h3 I have there.

My example would be Expires: September 09, 2011 :: 9 Days Remaining.

Maybe there is a different method for DateTime that would help?.

I'm doing my code inside of my .cshtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subtract `DateTime` values, and the result is a `TimeSpan` value. You can use the `Days` property to get the difference in days:

```
@((item2.VoucherCampaign.ExpiryDate - DateTime.Today).Days)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. That is exactly what I wanted. You = Lifesaver and you taught me something new today

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Subtract` method, and then the `Days` property of the result, like this:

`var remainingDays = futureDate.Subtract(DateTime.Today).Days`